# Java GSON JsonSerializer not convert Date type field of my model to Long value

Tags: java, json, date, gson

I have this method

```
public String prepareResponseJson(Object result, ResultCode resultCode, String details) {
        ResponseMessage responseMessage = new ResponseMessage<>(result, resultCode, details);
        return gson.toJson(responseMessage);
    }
```

and

```
JsonSerializer<Date> ser = (src, typeOfSrc, context) -> src == null ? null : new JsonPrimitive(src.getTime());
    JsonDeserializer<Date> deser = (json, typeOfT, context) -> json == null ? null : new Date(json.getAsLong());

        gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, ser)
                .registerTypeAdapter(Date.class, deser)
                .registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class,
                        new Serializer()).registerTypeAdapter(XMLGregorianCalendar.class,
                        new Deserializer())
                .serializeNulls().create();
```

When I tried serialize this filed of model

```
private java.util.Date lastModified;
```

I have this filed in Json string

```
"lastModified": "окт 8, 2015",
```

But model has this value

```
lastModified - 2015-10-08
```

Why Date convert vrong? In other places my converter(Date serializer/deserializer) work fine.

Comment: I don't get it: `Okt 8, 2015` and `2015-10-08` are just different representations of the same date. What's the problem?

Comment: The problem is that my JsonSerializer make Okt 8, 2015 and my JsonDeserializer on client can not Deserialize this string to Date. it must be serialized into Long

Comment: You might adapt your question then. "But model has this value `lastModified - 2015-10-08`" is misleading here, better directly state that you don't want the date as string but as long in your Json.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the data format when you are creating a GSON instance:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
   .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```

Comment: my JsonSerializer work fine on other models with date fields

Answer (score 0):

you can add your specific date format to GsonBuilder like this :

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").create();
```